# Separated sets written as union of disjoint closed sets can be separated

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets such that $\overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset = \overline{B}\cap A$. Furthermore, $A$ and $B$ can be written as a countable union of closed sets. I am trying to show that there exist disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $A$ is in $U$ and $B$ is in $V$. I am not sure where to start.

Note this is all happening in a normal T1 space.

Comment: Does it mimic the proof that Lindelof T3 implies normal

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).